# Reports doesn't use changes in content with query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportmanager

In SSRS I have changed some tablenames and want to change the queries in all the reports that use those tables.

I have no trouble changing the queries. But when I run the reports in reportmanager they still use the old code.

If I edit the report in reportbuilder I can see that the code is changed.

If I save the report in reportbuilder then the reportmanager uses the correct code.

How do I make the change through a query without having to open each report and saving it again?

Comment: You can't. This is why changing things like table names is generally a bad idea; as if you aren't using schema binding you will need to go and change **every** reference to it. Not just in the Databases objects, but in other projects (like SSRS) too. Another reason why i also find it easier to use SPs for SSRS, rather than putting the queries directly in the dataset.

Comment: Ok thank you. Unfortunately i dont make the reports but i will keep that in mind.
Make a solution so i can accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SYNONYM for the old table name to reference the new table name and your reports will still run correctly.

```
CREATE SYNONYM OldTableName FOR NewTableName
```

For more information please see this excellent introduction

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-synonym/